# Plot 1, ..., Plot 3 switches on TI-83 calculator

Tags: graphing-functions, calculator

My student has a TI-83 (I think - it is black, and newer than mine, and I have a TI-82), and she asked me what the three switches were, those at the top of the function list screen (where you input what is to become a graph) - the switches labeled `Plot1`, `Plot2`, and `Plot3`?

I told her 1) I don't know, and 2) I associate "plotting" with the practical side of drawing a graph from a data set, placing the spots to be joined by the function curve.

We did not understand it by experimenting, either.

I will email her any answers, so don't be shy to elaborate a couple of paragraphs on the purpose and usage of those switches.

Cheers

Comment: Here is the [TI-83 manual](http://education.ti.com/guidebooks/graphing/83/83gb.pdf). Do a search for *plot1*.

Comment: Without actually knowing what model it is, you could be stumbling around the wrong manuals. It appears that the TI-83, TI-83+, TI-84+, TI-85, and TI-89 could all match the physical description. Verify the model, then go to the source as others have suggested to get the manuals.

Comment: @dfeuer, and Git Gud, and amWhy: I am trying to solve a problem, by asking a question. If I don't get an answer, I will consider other ways to solve the problem, you don't need to worry or advice about that.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation would be "***go directly to the source***":

- See, e.g., [TI-83 Guide Book](http://education.ti.com/guidebooks/graphing/83/83gb.pdf)
- or visit the eduction site for [TI-83 Plus/silver-edition](http://education.ti.com/en/us/products/calculators/graphing-calculators/ti-83-plus/features/features-summary) to view the features, applications, and available "downloads", if your student has the "plus" model.

See also this "[feature tutorial](http://www.prenhall.com/divisions/esm/app/calculator/)" for graphic, step-by-step instructions for using various features of the TI- 83, and/or how to use them.

Comment: @Amzoti: The OP has got it, thanks to Git Gud.

Answer (score 1):

From pages 231-238 of the TI-83 UK [manual](http://education.ti.com/guidebooks/graphing/83/83gb.pdf), I have concluded that my intuition was correct: plotting is about drawing graphs, manually from a data set (although the calculator helps).

It is possible to plot six different diagrams: the data set(s) are interpreted differently for different diagrams.

The most simple example, perhaps, is a filled curve (a graph). Coordinates - the plots - are extracted from two lists, with `x` positions in one, and `y` positions in the other.

So, type the coordinates:

```
{1, 2, 3}->L1

{2, 4, 6}->L2
```

Then press [STAT PLOT].

An overview is shown. It is possible to have three plotted diagrams at work, at the same time. To experiment with the first (`Plot1`), press [1] or [ENTER].

Now, some details are shown:

- `On`/`Off` (draw the diagram or not - this can also be set by marking the `Plot1` switch in the [Y=] screen)
- `Type` (for a curve that passes through the plots, pick the middle icon on the top line)
- `Xlist` (the x:es, set to `L1` - use the specific one-character key)
- `Ylist` (the y:s, set to `L2`)
- `Mark` (how to show the plots when drawn: I suppose it doesn't really matter unless you have more than one diagram, and you like to keep them apart)

So, the coordinates are `(x, y) = (1, 2)`, `(2, 4)`, and `(3, 6)`!

Example when to use: Say that you have a data set of observations, and you wish to illustrate how close (or not close...) it follows a math function. Plot the data set, enable it, enter the function, draw, and compare.